# Ping system with multiple interfaces

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware, ipv6

Setup:

- Host machine: macOS, IPv6 address - 2002::3/64 (vmnet1)
- Guest machine: Ubuntu running inside vmware, IPv6 address - 2002::2/64 (eth0) and 2001::1/64 (tun0)

Configuration:

- Enabled IPv4 and IPv6 forwarding on Ubuntu
- Added route on macOS: `sudo route add -inet6 2001::/64 -interface vmnet1`

[image: configuration_setup_diagram]

Problem: I am unable to `ping6 2001::1` from macOS. However, I am able to `ping6 2002::2`. I have tried with "Share with my Mac", "Autodetect" and also "Private to Mac" settings of VMware.

Comment: Would recommend picking better address prefixes – not only are these two prefixes assigned for someone else, they actually have special-purpose assignments: 2001:0::/32 is Teredo, 2002::/16 is 6to4. There is always a possibility that an OS might treat them differently from other "normal" prefixes.

Comment: I tried with aaaa::/64 prefix too for tun0 interface. And also tried flusing iptables rules. I did ip6table -F. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to route 2001::/64 via vmnet1; you also have to specify *which gateway* on vmnet1 the packets should be sent to – 2002::2 in this case.

Without a gateway specification, the source will attempt to directly resolve the destination using ARP (for IPv4) or NDP (ICMPv6 Neighbour Discovery). However, IPv6 usually considers addresses as belonging to the individual interfaces or links, not the whole host – therefore IPv6 hosts usually ignore Neighbour Discovery requests if they arrive through an interface which doesn't have that address assigned. *(This is similar to Linux arp_ignore=1 for IPv4.)*

So the Ubuntu system won't respond to the NDP queries for 2001::1 arriving via eth0, because there is no such address on eth0 – it's only assigned on tun0. It will, however, respond to NDP queries for 2002::2, so your route should look like:

```
route add -inet6 2001::/64 2002::2
```

(That said, once the packets have been successfully routed via L2 to the correct MAC address, the Ubuntu system *will* accept and recognize 2001::1 in the IP header (L3), because that address is marked as local in its routing table.)